# sed + remove word from specific line

Tags: linux, text-processing, sed

we have this line from postgresql.conf file

```
#BARMAN# archive_command = 'rsync -a %p barman@107.16.25.69:/var/lib/barman/main-db-server/incoming/%f'
```

I remove the word -   #BARMAN# by the following sec syntax

```
sed '/archive_command/ s/#BARMAN#//g'
```

but the word archive_command not in the beginning of the line

as the following:

```
    archive_command = 'rsync -a %p barman@107.16.25.69:/var/lib/barman/main-db-server/incoming/%f'
```

while expected output should be

```
archive_command = 'rsync -a %p barman@107.16.25.69:/var/lib/barman/main-db-server/incoming/%f'
```

how to fix that?

Comment: sed '/archive_command/ s/#BARMAN#[ ]*//g' ?

Comment: sed -E 's/^#BARMAN#[[:blank:]]//g'

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Notice that you are only replacing `#BARMAN#`, and not the space(s) afterwards.

To do that, use

```
sed '/archive_command/s/#BARMAN# *//'
```

or, to allow for tabs as well as spaces:

```
sed '/archive_command/s/#BARMAN#[[:space:]]*//'
```

This will remove the string and any number of spaces or tabs directly afterwards.